# How do I update multiple records from one post that returns a collection?

Tags: angularjs, ajax, laravel-5.1

I have an AngularJS form that uses ng-repeat and ng-form to populate a list of users that can be marked as here or not.

I am now trying to use AJAX to submit the updated field to Laravel.

My form request is trying to POST a collection and update one column for multiple records.  Nothing seems to be happening, no errors.

I suspect there is something wrong with my method.

```
  public function setRoster(Request $request, $id) {
            $players[] = $request;
            foreach ($players as $player) {
                Player::where('playerId', $player->playerId)
                ->update(array('gamesPlayed' => $id));
            }
        }
```

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Here is the JSON from the POST

```
Request {#39
  #json: ParameterBag {#31
    #parameters: array:1 [
      "players" => array:22 [
        0 => array:15 [
          "playerId" => 1
          "teamId" => "6"
          "number" => "2"
          "position" => "unknown"
          "gamesPlayed" => ""
          "tempNumbers" => ""
          "firstName" => "Tom"
          "lastName" => "Travis"
          "dob" => "1968-10-01"
          "email" => "tom@hotmail.com"
          "mobile" => ""
          "photo" => "headshot.jpg"
          "created_at" => "-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
          "updated_at" => "-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
          "onIce" => true
        ]
```

and so on...

So based on feedback, I have tried this;

```
foreach ($request as $player) {
        Player::where('playerId', $player['playerId'])->update('gamesPlayed', '=', $id);
    }
```

Which is now returning this error;

Cannot use object of type Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag as array

Comment: `$players[] = $request` is probably not right...

Comment: Correct.  So, if I remove the [ ] and then dump $players I get an JSON collection of records.  How do I iterate through that and update each one with the new value?

Right now I get this error:

Undefined property: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag::$playerId

Comment: Could please display the JSON collection in order to know the structure?

Comment: Added to question above.  Thanks.

Comment: `$request` is a bag of all information, not only values of your form. You should use `$request->all()` or `$request['aSpecificFieldName']` or `$request->only(['aSpecificFieldName','anotherFieldName','anotherOne'])`

Comment: So defining $players as $request so I can iterate through the data is not required?  Do I format the foreach as $requests as $request?

Comment: I have tried the added code above in the question.

Comment: Answered here - https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-do-i-update-records-from-a-collection